# Дождаться завершения потока

Tags: c++, boost

Потоки создаются в цикле, и их количество заранее не известно

```
threads.push_back(boost::thread(readFile, it->path()));
```

Как узнать, когда все такие потоки завершили работу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например,

```
for (auto& t : threads)
    t.join();
```

?

Comment: Да, спасибо. Самое интересное, что я умудрился убрать из кода эту проверку, пока решал другие проблемы :D

Comment: @Виталий: Ну вот и хорошо. Пожалуйста!